# Add content to multiple (txt) files python

Tags: python, string, list, file, addition

I need over 2000 dummy (txt) files voor testing a recycle bin function. I've created the txt dummy files with the following code:

```
list = range(0,2000)
vulling = list

with open("path/file.txt", "w") as f:
for s in vulling:
    f.write(str(s) +"\n")

List = open("path/file.txt")
List2 = (s.strip() + ' dummy' for s in List)
for item in List2: 
    open('path/%s.txt'%(item,), 'w')
```

But, since I can't upload empty files, I need to add content to those files. The content can be the same for all those files. For example: add a string "Spam" to every file. What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: Are you asking about adding the content to the files while you are creating them or after they are created? And when do you close those functions in your code?

Comment: That doesn't matter... The goal is to create +2000 files with some content. Till now I have the code that will create 2000 files, but with no content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just to create the files with the content in them that you want to begin with:

```
import os.path


def create_test_files(target_dir, content, n=2000, template="file_%s.txt"):
    for i in xrange(n):
        path = os.path.join(target_dir, template % i)
        with open(path, 'w') as fh:
            fh.write(content)

        yield path


for file_name in create_test_files("/tmp/example", 'Spam'):
    print file_name
```

This is choosing file names for you, so if you need specific ones, you'll have to change it.

This is really quite fast. The other approach (create then copy) will result in having to read the original file 2000 times. Seeing as we already know the content we want in there, we can save that time.

**Note:** This solution uses a generator, so unless you force it to iterate (e.g. by putting it in loop, or tuple), it won't generate any files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! While I am quite new to the python world, I understand that adding content before creating the files will take less time than rather giving content to existing files. But I am not (yet) familiar with the generators. So I have to this peace of code in loop? When creating the code I remain with a "invalid syntax" error on the tuple part....

Comment: I've modified the example to loop over the results and print them out. If you don't need the filenames, you can comment out the yield and call the function normally. If you can build up the values in a list and return them in a function to get the same result. The above works for me in python 2.7